# weird glass effect artifacts - Principled BSDF, Transmission 1

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm a filmmaker and 2d motion designer that's starting his journey in 3d. Following blender guru tutorial I've encountered first major problem that I cannot overcome. I have those weird artifacts when try to apply glass shader onto the cup. The plate renders fine, but the cup has artifacts (it's the same material on a plate and on a cup.

[image]

Do you maybe have any ideas how to resolve this?[image]

Comment: Hello :). This can have many reasons. The fastest way is to [share your .blend](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) so others can take a look

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=Eam1LJlM" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/Eam1LJlM/) Sure, here it is :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice cup! But it has 2 issues:

1. duplicated vertices
2. flipped normals

When you turn on `Face Orientation` in the overlays, you will see your cup is mostly red (flipped normals) and there is some flickering/pixel fight going on (duplicates).

To fix it select the cup, switch to edit mode, select all vertices with key <kbd>A</kbd>, then press <kbd>M</kbd> to open the `merge` context menu. There, select `by distance` to get rid of the duplicated vertices.
Then press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals (outside).

Comment: Worked like charm. Thank you very much!